# How to add basicConstraints extention to a self signed certificate

Tags: tls, certificates, linux, openssl

Using openssl to create a self signed certificate. The certificate needs to have the Basic Constraints value defined and showing in the cert but I can't seem to be finding the right location to modify in the openssl.cnf file. So far all of my certs are missing this field so I must be editing the cnf file wrong. Does anyone know what I need to change in the cnf file to make this happen. Running openssl 1.0.1f. I'm also using the -extfile in my x509 command for the SAN if that matters. (There is a section in the file that talks about adding extentions if you are using -extfile.

Comment: I can post the file contents if requested.

Comment: found and followed this - http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm - problem solved